# 5/multi-year year forecast average measure in DAX

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a [Profit] measure in my 'Data' table and a linked 'Calendar' table with a column YEARS that I use as the column header in my pivot. In total, there are 8 years.

I want to calculate for each column/year on the pivot the total profit for the next 5 years (including the current one). In year 6, there are only two additional years left, so it should then only sum those three years (i.e. MAX(5, #yrs left)).

I've tried various time intelligence functions to no success; help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sample data with expected output is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
Profit Fwd Rolling 5 Years = 
var from_date = CALCULATE (MIN('Calendar'[Date]))
var rtn = CALCULATE ([Profit], DATESINPERIOD ('Calendar'[Date], from_date, 5, YEAR))
RETURN rtn
```

Note that this solution uses the Time Intelligence function DATESINPERIOD. In order for this to work, you need a calendar table with all dates, not just years. That table has to be marked as the Date Table for the model. Substitute whatever name you give to the column with the date value for 'Calendar'[Date].

Comment: I see the logic but for some reason I don't have time to explore, this gave inexplicable, wrong numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this for now:

```
[Profit Fwd] =
VAR CurrentYear = MAX('Calendar'[Year])

RETURN

CALCULATE(SUMX('Calendar',[Profit]), AND('Calendar'[Year] <= CurrentYear+4,'Calendar'[Year]>=CurrentYear), ALL('Calendar'[Year]))
```